# What is the order of evaluations of parameters inside the function?

Tags: function, sml

Having something like `foo(bar1(), bar2())` can I be sure in SML that it will always evaluate `bar1()` first and after `bar2()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Strictly speaking you have a function which is applied to a tuple. Fields of a tuple are evaluated from left to right so *bar1()* will be evaluated before *bar2()*.  See "The Definition of Standard ML (Revised)" by Milner, Tofte, Harper and MacQueen page 41.

Note that if *foo* is actually an expression that could have side-effects or raise an exception it will be evaluated before its argument and therefore before either *bar1()* or *bar2()*.  This particularly has implications with curried applications.

```
foo (bar1()) (bar2())
```

Will evaluate first *bar1()* then *foo(bar1value)* before evaluating *bar2()*.